# If $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, find the transformation matrix with respect to a given basis of $V$ and a given basis of $W$

Tags: linear-transformations

Suppose that $T(x, y) = (2x + 3y, 2x + 5y, 3x + 4y)$.

If $Bv$ is a basis of $V$ such that $Bv = \{(1, 2); (3, 1)\}$ and

if $Bw$ is a basis of $W$ such that $Bw = \{(1, 2, 3); (4, 1, 2); (3, 4, 1)\}$,

then what steps would I have to take to find the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases? Please don't just give me the answer. I need to know how to get it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $x \in V $. Then if we call $v_1, v_2$ the basis $B_V $ we know that  $x = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$

Then calculating $T(x) = T(\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) = T(\alpha v_1) + T(\beta v_2) = \alpha T(v_1) + \beta T(v_2) $

Thus to calculate the image of any vector $x $ we only need the values of $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2) $.

But $T(v_1), T(v_2) $ are easily computable. Let us call them $v'_1$ and $v'_2$. Because each of the $v'$ is a vector from $W $, they can be written as a sum of the vectors from $B_W = \{w_1, w_2, w_3\} $.

This yields

$$\begin{cases}
T(v_1) = v'_1 = a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2 + a_3 w_3\\
T(v_2) = v'_2 = b_1 w_1 + b_2 w_2 + b_3 w_3\end{cases}$$

Now we know that a linear transformation has, in its columns, the images of the different vectors from the basis, meaning the columns of the matrix you want are precisely the images of $v_1$ and $v_2$ written in the basis $B_W $, i.e. the matrix will take the form

$$\begin {bmatrix} a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2\\
a_3 & b_3\end {bmatrix} $$

All you have to do is compute those factors $a_i $ and $b_i $.

Comment: What role do alpha and beta play?

Comment: @clockadd for your calculations, none.they just show that we only care about the images of v1 and v2

Comment: Alright. I think I've got it. Thanks.