# Finding Matrix representation of T, relative to B, C

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the matrix representation of the following linear transformations
T: R2$\rightarrow$ R2  defined  by  T $\binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}} = \binom{3x_{1}-2x_{2}}{x_{1}}$  Where  $\beta$ = { $b_{1}$ = $\binom{2}{1}$,$b_{2}$=$\binom{1}{3}$ and  C = {$c_{1}$ = $\binom{2}{1}$,$c_{2}$=$\binom{1}{3}$}

I know I need to plugin, well I think I need to plug in $b_{1}$, $b_{2}$ into the T $\binom{x_{1}}{x_{2}} = \binom{3x_{1}-2x_{2}}{x_{1}}$. That's about as far as I've gotten. Guidance requested.

Comment: Consider reading this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015923/329832 and its answer

Comment: The answer is clear, but I have trouble with example that don't use actual and only variables. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(2,1)=(4,2)=2(2,1)+0(1,3)$ and that $T(1,3)=(-3,1)=-2(2,1)+1(1,3)$ so the matrix for the operator will be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
    2     &  -2  \\
   0       & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

It is important to remember that the nth column of a matrix of an operator represents the scalars of the linear combination of the transformed basis member
 with respect to that basis.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard matrix for the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is $P =  \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{p_1} & \mathbf{p_2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ because, for $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3x_1 - 2x_2 \\ x_1 \end{bmatrix}$. Given a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\mathbf{b_1}, \mathbf{b_2}\} = \bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\bigg\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the matrix for the linear transformation relative to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is

$$P_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatrix} [\mathbf{p_1}]_{\mathcal{B}} & [\mathbf{p_2}]_{\mathcal{B}} \end{bmatrix}$$

where

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{b_1} & \mathbf{b_2} \end{bmatrix} [\mathbf{p_1}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \mathbf{p_1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{b_1} & \mathbf{b_2} \end{bmatrix} [\mathbf{p_2}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \mathbf{p_2}$$

Suppose $[\mathbf{p_1}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $[\mathbf{p_2}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving the above equations, we get

$$P_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatrix} [\mathbf{p_1}]_{\mathcal{B}} & [\mathbf{p_2}]_{\mathcal{B}} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 8/5 & -6/5 \\ -1/5 & 2/5 \end{bmatrix}$$

The steps to finding the standard matrix for the linear transformation $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal{C}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ should be similar. By the way, you may have a typo, because according to your post, $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Well damn, now I'm confused. The top answer seemed like the correct way.

Comment: Notice that, if $\mathbf{x_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $[\mathbf{x_1}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. And, if $\mathbf{x_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, then $[\mathbf{x_2}]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatix} -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. And so, those are the _coordinates_ of the transformation of $\mathbf{x_1}$ and  $\mathbf{x_2}$ by $P_\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 8/5 & -6/5 \\ -1/5 & 2/5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix} 8/5 & -6/5 \\ -1/5 & 2/5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. And so, I don't think $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix for the linear transformation $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Sorry my first garbled comment above; please ignore it as it's incorrect anyway. I'm still new to SE. Apparently I can't edit my own comments...

Comment: Haha no thx for clearing that up. Took me like 30 min to make my post, i understand your pain.